# How to call a shell script using a button present in Excel?

Tags: shell, vbscript

I need to call a bash script "AVFoRGe" present in a Dir "XX" by pressing a button called "RUN" present in an Excel named InputExcel in the Dir "XX".

Comment: You question should be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that you have to do is "Assign macro" into your button by right clicking on the button, "Asign Macro", and then click "New".
and then copy this code inside of tag sub `run_click()` and end sub.

```
shell(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\AVFoRGe.bat")
```